# Ray tracing for dummies

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, pixel, raytracing

This is a difficult question: I'm searching for masterfully explained/exceptionally explained books/tutorials/whatever regarding ray tracing (Kd-trees, barycentric oordinates).

By "masterfully explained" I mean books which don't look like a latex proof-of-concept paper published on ieee but thoroughly explain a concept (doesn't matter if the book is huge) with examples and doesn't assume that the reader is a mathematician and may have doubts on anything.

Can somebody help me in this quest? Optionally one might link resources for graphics-related math and other for ray-tracing (if the same argument doesn't fit into one category)

Comment: The definition of "not constructive" on this site is a question that asks for polls, personal preferences, debates, discussion.

Comment: The problem is "personal preferences" should not include things well-explained

Comment: Read the definition of not constructive.

Comment: I agree that this is not the correct forum for these sorts of questions.  I would be more inclined to check review sites or contact universities regarding this.  That said, *Computer Graphics, Principles and Practice* by Foley and van Dam is a classic book in the subject of graphics, and was for years considered a sort of bible.

Comment: @paddy : The Foley/Van Dam book was a classic (I used to have a copy of the 2nd edition) in its time, however by today's standard it is quite dated. Most of the book covers low-level topics like rasterisation of lines and circles that aren't really necessary today. I don't recall there being any chapters covering ray-tracing either.

Answer (score 2):

"Physically Based Rendering, Second Edition" by Matt Pharr & Greg Humpreys is comprehensive, though the emphasis is on path-tracing rather than ray-tracing. The web site has the source code for PBRT, a fully functional path-tracer. This book is relatively advanced.

"Ray Tracing from the Ground Up" by Kevin Suffern is a more gentle introduction, with the emphasis on ray-tracing. Later chapters introduce path-tracing. This is a better book for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

[*An Introduction to Ray Tracing*](http://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Ray_Tracing.html?id=YPblYyLqBM4C), edited by Andrew S. Glassner, covers a lot of the core topics of ray tracing as separate articles.  The organization makes it easy to skip around and focus on the topics you want.